# Word problem involving instantanous velocity and acceleration

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, word-problem

I'll try to explain this clear enough:

Let's say a baseball is "popped up" into the air, and it's height (meters) after t minutes is represented by the function $f(t) = -4.9t^2+25t+3$.

I have to find the instantaneous velocity and the acceleration of $t$ when $t = 2$.

Would I be able to use the power rule to get the derivative of this function, and then plug in 2 to find the instantaneous velocity? Then would I be able to find the second derivative to find the acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $v(t) = -9.8t + 25$ and $a(t) = -9.8$.

Then $v(2) = 5.4$ and $a(2) = -9.8$.

To solve for when the ball hits the ground we simply set $f(t) = 0$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: How could I find out how long it was in the air

Comment: **Hint:** what's the height of the ball when it hits the ground?

Comment: When it hit's the ground, wouldn't the height be 0?

Comment: Indeed and you have a function that relates height and time.

Comment: So i'm guessing I just plug in zeros for t then?

Comment: Your function gives you height as a function of time, if you plugged in zeroes for $t$ then your function would return the height of the ball at time zero. That is not what you want.

Comment: So I would plug in the time when the ball hits the ground, and since the height is a function of time, this would give me the answer?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I mean the height is a function of time. Your function $f$ takes input $t$ t is a time, it outputs the height. You're trying to solve for $t$ the time when the ball hits the ground. You know the height is zero. Does this make more sense? You won't be plugging anything into $t$, you're trying to solve for $t$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21450/discussion-between-c0der-and-egokilla).

Comment: The function $f(t)=−4.9t^2+25t+3$ is way of finding height knowing $t$, but here is vice versa you know that height is zero or $f(t)=0$. So you just need to solve the equation you get from this.

Answer (score 0):

When you find first derivative you can instantly find second. So you will have 2 formulas and by plugging in $t$ in two of them you can get separately instantaneous velocity and acceleration. $\frac{d}{dt}f=-9.8t + 25$ is first derivative, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f=-9.8$ is second one. So instantaneous acceleration is seen without plugging any $t$ and equals $-9.8\frac{m}{sec^2}$